# URL Doesn't Show Current Page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am writing a starter react app that provides responsiveness to the device, has a navigation bar with standard navigation items (about, contact, register, login logout, and home).  The current page is changed in the navigation bar when the user clicks a link.  However some pages are not intended to be changed by a click.  One of the navigation bar functions is "Login".  This calls a component called the Login page.  Once the user attempts to login, an AJAX call is done to the database to verify the login information.  If successful, I want to load the "dashboard" page.  This works, but because I am not clicking on a link in the navigation bar to load this page, the URL still shows "localhost/login" instead of "/localhost/dashboard" even when the dashboard is displayed.  I am pretty sure the problem is because I didn't click on a link to get there - it was done programmatically.  So I'm trying to programmatically change the URL in these cases to match the page displayed.

I've done google searches on programmatically changing the url.  Also searched on react-router and using NavLink.  I tried adding debug console.log statements in my navigation bar to see if I was trying to render after changing the active page to the dashboard.  I'm not sure what else to do now.  I am new to react (just enough knowledge to be dangerous)

This is from App.js.  It renders a Toolbar.  The toolbar renders the navigation bar.  My state is maintained in App.js and is passed to the other components as props.  The code below isn't all the code, but I'm trying to include what is needed to understand it but not overwhelm.

```
const initialState = {
  sideDrawerOpen: false,
  loggedIn: false,
  userID: "",
  fullName: "",
  activePage: "HOME_PAGE",
  pageBody: <Home />
};

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = initialState;
  }

...

callback function for login component

  loginCallback = (retCode, userID, fullName, message) => {
    switch (retCode) {
      // User logged in successfully
      case 0:
        alert(message);
        break;

      // ID not valid
      case 1:
        alert(message);
        break;

      // Password Must Be Changed
      case 2:
        alert(message);
        break;

      // User Locked Out
      case 3:
        alert(message);
        break;

      // Password Incorrect
      case 4:
        alert(message);
        break;

      // Database error
      default:
        alert(message);
        break;
    }

    let newState;

    if (retCode === 0) {
      newState = {
        sideDrawerOpen: this.state.sideDrawerOpen,
        loggedIn: true,
        userID: userID,
        fullName: fullName,
        activePage: "DASHBOARD_PAGE",
        pageBody: <Dashboard />
      };
    } else {
      newState = {
        sideDrawerOpen: this.state.sideDrawerOpen,
        loggedIn: false,
        userID: "",
        fullName: "",
        activePage: this.state.activePage,
        pageBody: this.state.pageBody
      };
    }

    this.setState(newState);
  };

appCallback function (when user clicks on navigation link).  This is passed to the Toolbar component which passes it through to the Navigation Bar component.

  appCallback = newActivePage => {
    let sdo = false;
    let li = this.state.loggedIn;
    let uid = this.state.userID;
    let fnm = this.state.fullName;
    let ap = this.state.activePage;
    let pb = this.state.pageBody;

    if (newActivePage === this.state.activePage) return;
    else {
      if (newActivePage === "REGISTER_PAGE") {
        ap = "REGISTER_PAGE";
        pb = <Register registerCallback={this.registerCallback} />;
      } else if (newActivePage === "LOGIN_PAGE") {
        ap = "LOGIN_PAGE";
        pb = (
          <Login
            loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn}
            userID={this.state.userID}
            fullName={this.state.fullName}
            loginCallback={this.loginCallback}
          />
        );
      } else if (newActivePage === "DASHBOARD_PAGE") {
        ap = "DASHBOARD_PAGE";
        pb = <Dashboard />;
      } else if (newActivePage === "HOME_PAGE") {
        ap = "HOME_PAGE";
        pb = <Home />;
      } else if (newActivePage === "ABOUT_PAGE") {
        ap = "ABOUT_PAGE";
        pb = <About />;
      } else if (newActivePage === "CONTACT_PAGE") {
        ap = "CONTACT_PAGE";
        pb = <Contact />;
      } else if (newActivePage === "LOGOUT_PAGE") {
        li = false;
        uid = "";
        fnm = "";
        ap = "HOME_PAGE";
        pb = <Home />;
      }

      let newState = {
        sideDrawerOpen: sdo,
        loggedIn: li,
        userID: uid,
        fullName: fnm,
        activePage: ap,
        pageBody: pb
      };

      this.setState(newState);
    }
  };


return (
      <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Toolbar
            drawerClickHandler={this.drawerToggleClickHandler}
            appCallback={this.appCallback}
            loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn}
            activePage={this.state.activePage}
          />
          <SideDrawer
            show={this.state.sideDrawerOpen}
            appCallback={this.appCallback}
            loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn}
            activePage={this.state.activePage}
          />
          {backdrop}
          <div>{this.state.pageBody}</div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );

END of App.js code
Beginning of Toolbar.js

class Toolbar extends Component {
  myCallback = pageToShow => {
    this.props.appCallback(pageToShow);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header className="toolbar">
          <nav className="toolbar__navigation">
            <div className="toolbar__toggle-button">
              <DrawerToggleButton click={this.props.drawerClickHandler} />
            </div>
            <div className="toolbar__logo">
              <a href="/">THE LOGO</a>
            </div>
            <div className="spacer" />
            <div>
              <Navigation
                tbCallback={this.myCallback}
                loggedIn={this.props.loggedIn}
                activePage={this.props.activePage}
              />
            </div>
          </nav>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Toolbar;
END of Toolbar Snippet.
Beginning of Navigation.js

const Navigation = props => {
  let cnREGISTER = "";
  let cnLOGIN = "";
  let cnLOGOUT = "";
  let cnHOME = "";
  let cnABOUT = "";
  let cnCONTACT = "";
  let cnDASHBOARD = "";

  console.log("in navigation.js");

  switch (props.loggedIn) {
    case true:
      cnREGISTER = "toolbar_navigation-items hidenavitem";
      cnLOGIN = "toolbar_navigation-items hidenavitem";
      cnLOGOUT = "toolbar_navigation-items shownavitem";

      if (props.activePage === "DASHBOARD_PAGE") {
        cnDASHBOARD = "toolbar_navigation-items-noselect shownavitem";
        console.log("DASHBOARD_PAGE is active page");
      } else cnDASHBOARD = "toolbar_navigation-items shownavitem";

      if (props.activePage === "HOME_PAGE")
        cnHOME = "toolbar_navigation-items-noselect shownavitem";
      else cnHOME = "toolbar_navigation-items shownavitem";

      if (props.activePage === "ABOUT_PAGE")
        cnABOUT = "toolbar_navigation-items-noselect shownavitem";
      else cnABOUT = "toolbar_navigation-items shownavitem";

      if (props.activePage === "CONTACT_PAGE")
        cnCONTACT = "toolbar_navigation-items-noselect shownavitem";
      else cnCONTACT = "toolbar_navigation-items shownavitem";
      break;

    case false:
      cnDASHBOARD = "toolbar_navigation-items hidenavitem";
      cnLOGOUT = "toolbar_navigation-items hidenavitem";

      if (props.activePage === "REGISTER_PAGE")
        cnREGISTER = "toolbar_navigation-items-noselect shownavitem";
      else cnREGISTER = "toolbar_navigation-items shownavitem";

      if (props.activePage === "LOGIN_PAGE")
        cnLOGIN = "toolbar_navigation-items-noselect shownavitem";
      else cnLOGIN = "toolbar_navigation-items shownavitem";

      if (props.activePage === "HOME_PAGE")
        cnHOME = "toolbar_navigation-items-noselect shownavitem";
      else cnHOME = "toolbar_navigation-items shownavitem";

      if (props.activePage === "ABOUT_PAGE")
        cnABOUT = "toolbar_navigation-items-noselect shownavitem";
      else cnABOUT = "toolbar_navigation-items shownavitem";

      if (props.activePage === "CONTACT_PAGE")
        cnCONTACT = "toolbar_navigation-items-noselect shownavitem";
      else cnCONTACT = "toolbar_navigation-items shownavitem";
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={cnLOGOUT}>
        <NavLink
          to="/logoff"
          onClick={props.tbCallback.bind(this, "LOGOUT_PAGE")}
        >
          Logout
        </NavLink>
      </div>
      <div className={cnREGISTER}>
        <NavLink
          to="/register"
          onClick={props.tbCallback.bind(this, "REGISTER_PAGE")}
        >
          Register
        </NavLink>
      </div>
      <div className={cnLOGIN}>
        <NavLink
          to="/login"
          onClick={props.tbCallback.bind(this, "LOGIN_PAGE")}
        >
          Login
        </NavLink>
      </div>
      <div className={cnDASHBOARD}>
        <NavLink
          to="/dashboard"
          onClick={props.tbCallback.bind(this, "DASHBOARD_PAGE")}
        >
          Dashboard
        </NavLink>
      </div>
      <div className={cnHOME}>
        <NavLink to="/" onClick={props.tbCallback.bind(this, "HOME_PAGE")}>
          Home
        </NavLink>
      </div>
      <div className={cnABOUT}>
        <NavLink
          to="/about"
          onClick={props.tbCallback.bind(this, "ABOUT_PAGE")}
        >
          About
        </NavLink>
      </div>
      <div className={cnCONTACT}>
        <NavLink
          to="/contact"
          onClick={props.tbCallback.bind(this, "CONTACT_PAGE")}
        >
          Contact
        </NavLink>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
END of Navigation.js snippet.
Beginning of Login snippet (just the AJAX stuff and login callback)

  handleSubmit = e => {
    var retCode;
    var userID;
    var fullName;
    var message;
    var xhr;
    var jsonData;

    e.preventDefault();

    if (formValid(this.state)) {
      var self = this;
      console.log("Submitting Login Form");

      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // only run if request is complete
        if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return;

        // process the return data
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
          // request is successful, process results
          jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          console.log(jsonData);

          retCode = jsonData.returncode;
          userID = jsonData.userID;
          fullName = jsonData.fullname;
          message = jsonData.message;

          self.props.loginCallback(retCode, userID, fullName, message);
        }
      };

      xhr.open("POST", "/php/login.php", true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      xhr.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          username: this.state.userName,
          password: this.state.password
        })
      );
    } else {
      console.log("Form Invalid");
    }
  };
```

I appreciate any responses I get on how to solve this.

I expect to see the url "localhost/dashboard" when the active page being displayed is actually the dashboard page.  The url displayed is actually the url to the login page "localhost/login"

Comment: can you share a codepen or a github repo link

Comment: You can simply use `this.props.history.push` to redirect to the desired path.

Comment: I tried adding this.props.history.push("/dashboard") to my code after successful login, but now it just sits on the login page and does not display the dashboard page.